# how can we publish a dotnet core app in netlify?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, build, netlify

i am trying to publish an app for homework in netlify. but when i try to deploy it gives error.

this is deploy log.

> 9:25:34 PM: Build ready to start 9:25:36 PM: build-image version:
>   30f629161c0736b1a3ecd8b418e5eeffab5c0faf 9:25:36 PM: build-image tag:
>   v3.3.14 9:25:36 PM: buildbot version:
>   80440c4491d323247b9d55f7bea2ea6bc96ce8d2 9:25:36 PM: Fetching cached
>   dependencies 9:25:37 PM: Starting to download cache of 252.0MB 9:25:38
>   PM: Finished downloading cache in 1.125171279s 9:25:38 PM: Starting to
>   extract cache 9:25:47 PM: Finished extracting cache in 9.35605714s
>   9:25:47 PM: Finished fetching cache in 10.542038119s 9:25:47 PM:
>   Starting to prepare the repo for build 9:25:47 PM: Preparing Git
>   Reference refs/heads/master 9:25:48 PM: Starting build script 9:25:48
>   PM: Installing dependencies 9:25:49 PM: Started restoring cached node
>   version 9:25:51 PM: Finished restoring cached node version 9:25:52 PM:
>   v10.20.1 is already installed. 9:25:53 PM: Now using node v10.20.1
>   (npm v6.14.4) 9:25:53 PM: Started restoring cached build plugins
>   9:25:53 PM: Finished restoring cached build plugins 9:25:53 PM:
>   Attempting ruby version 2.6.2, read from environment 9:25:54 PM: Using
>   ruby version 2.6.2 9:25:54 PM: Using PHP version 5.6 9:25:54 PM: 5.2
>   is already installed. 9:25:54 PM: Using Swift version 5.2 9:25:54 PM:
>   Started restoring cached go cache 9:25:54 PM: Finished restoring
>   cached go cache 9:25:54 PM: go version go1.12 linux/amd64 9:25:54 PM:
>   go version go1.12 linux/amd64 9:25:54 PM: Installing missing commands
>   9:25:54 PM: Verify run directory 9:25:54 PM: Executing user command:
>   dotnet build 9:25:59 PM: Microsoft (R) Build Engine version
>   16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e for .NET Core 9:25:59 PM: Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. 9:26:01 PM:   Determining projects
>   to restore... 9:26:04 PM:   Restored
>   /opt/build/repo/Electronic-Products-Market-Database-Management-System.csproj
>   (in 2.21 sec). 9:26:12 PM:
>   Electronic-Products-Market-Database-Management-System ->
>   /opt/build/repo/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Electronic-Products-Market-Database-Management-System.dll
>   9:26:12 PM:   Electronic-Products-Market-Database-Management-System ->
>   /opt/build/repo/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Electronic-Products-Market-Database-Management-System.Views.dll
>   9:26:13 PM: Build succeeded. 9:26:13 PM:     0 Warning(s) 9:26:13 PM: 
>   0 Error(s) 9:26:13 PM: Time Elapsed 00:00:13.37 9:26:13 PM: Skipping
>   functions preparation step: no functions directory set 9:26:13 PM:
>   Caching artifacts 9:26:13 PM: Started saving build plugins 9:26:13 PM:
>   Finished saving build plugins 9:26:13 PM: Started saving pip cache
>   9:26:20 PM: Finished saving pip cache 9:26:20 PM: Started saving emacs
>   cask dependencies 9:26:20 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
>   9:26:20 PM: Started saving maven dependencies 9:26:20 PM: Finished
>   saving maven dependencies 9:26:20 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
>   9:26:20 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies 9:26:20 PM: Started
>   saving go dependencies 9:26:20 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
>   9:26:20 PM:  9:26:20 PM: ** WARNING ** 9:26:20 PM: There are some
>   lingering processes even after the build process finished: 9:26:20 PM:
>   USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME
>   COMMAND 9:26:20 PM: buildbot    1285 27.9  0.6 28786512 187172 ?
>   Sl   18:26   0:03 /opt/buildhome/.dotnet/dotnet exec
>   /opt/buildhome/.dotnet/sdk/3.1.300/Roslyn/bincore/VBCSCompiler.dll
>   -pipename:32wBLnYyW2__v++qn9hs3AnpT7QZOsyeYeOn6hJdLao 9:26:20 PM: buildbot    1311 20.5  0.4 28228864 128840 ?     Sl   18:26   0:02
>   /opt/buildhome/.dotnet/dotnet
>   /opt/buildhome/.dotnet/sdk/3.1.300/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor/tools/netcoreapp3.0/rzc.dll
>   server -p buildbot.XiJojHVTENZ4oaYBDyZsHSy+b 9:26:20 PM: Our builds do
>   not kill your processes automatically, so please make sure 9:26:20 PM:
>   that nothing is running after your build finishes, or it will be
>   marked as 9:26:20 PM: failed since something is still running. 9:26:20
>   PM:  9:26:20 PM: Build script success 9:26:20 PM: Starting to deploy
>   site from 'bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/publish' 9:26:20 PM: Creating
>   deploy tree  9:26:20 PM: Creating deploy upload records 9:26:20 PM: 0
>   new files to upload 9:26:20 PM: 0 new functions to upload 9:26:20 PM:
>   Starting post processing 9:26:20 PM: Post processing done 9:26:20 PM:
>   Site is live 9:27:02 PM: Finished processing build request in
>   1m25.952288421s

if you know a guide for building dotnet core apps on netlify let me know.

Comment: 1. As an orthogonal issue, you should use `dotnet publish`, not `dotnet build` for publishing applications. 2. I have only seen netlify docs mention *static* websites. ASP.NET Core applications are the opposite of static websites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## It's not possible.

I searched Netilfy docs. What you are asking for is not possible: https://community.netlify.com/t/support-guide-can-i-run-a-web-server-http-listener-and-or-database-at-netlify/3078:

> How do I run a server/database at Netlify?
>
> We often get questions about how to run a specific backend server or > database at Netlify. Examples of these types of questions include:
>
> - How to I get my node HTTP listener to respond to requests?
> - How do I start Mongo/MySQL/ running on the server?
> - How can I SSH into my website?
>
> We are here today to answer these questions - and the answer is: You can’t!
>
> ... the CDN/ADN at Netlify only serves static files....

## Original Answer

And some hints to debug the issue.

Did you read the error message in its entirety? It says:

```
9:26:20 PM: ** WARNING ** 
9:26:20 PM: There are some lingering processes even after the build process finished
```

And then

```
9:26:20 PM: Our builds do not kill your processes automatically, so please make sure
9:26:20 PM: that nothing is running after your build finishes, or it will be marked as
9:26:20 PM: failed since something is still running.
```

It even tells you what's running:

```
9:26:20 PM: USER PID %CPU %MEM VSZ RSS TTY STAT START TIME COMMAND
9:26:20 PM: buildbot 1285 27.9 0.6 28786512 187172 ? Sl 18:26 0:03 /opt/buildhome/.dotnet/dotnet exec /opt/buildhome/.dotnet/sdk/3.1.300/Roslyn/bincore/VBCSCompiler.dll -pipename:32wBLnYyW2__v++qn9hs3AnpT7QZOsyeYeOn6hJdLao 
9:26:20 PM: buildbot 1311 20.5 0.4 28228864 128840 ? Sl 18:26 0:02 /opt/buildhome/.dotnet/dotnet /opt/buildhome/.dotnet/sdk/3.1.300/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor/tools/netcoreapp3.0/rzc.dll server -p buildbot.XiJojHVTENZ4oaYBDyZsHSy+b
```

It looks like 2 `dotnet` processes are still running at the end of your build and that makes the build as failed. These are the .NET Core compile server (`VBCSCompiler.dll`) and the Razor pages compiler (`rzc.dll`).

This is a pretty well known issue: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/9487. To quote that bug report:

> Use `-p:UseRazorBuildServer=false` to disable the Razor (rzc) server.
>
> Use `-p:UseSharedCompilation=false` to disable the Roslyn (vbcscompiler) server.

So modify your `dotnet build` (or `publish`) command to run like this:

```
dotnet build -p:UseRazorBuildServer=false -p:UseSharedCompilation=false [your other options]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you use Netlify to serve static files ***and*** use MAUI (IOW you rely on the client).

Install the dependencies for your CI/CD scenario.

Adjust the directories accordingly:

```
Set the base directory: Release/net6.0/browser-wasm/publish/wwwroot
Build command: dotnet publish -c Release -o release
Publish directory: Release/net6.0/browser-wasm/publish/wwwroot/
```

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions or if you need further assistance.